# CS50 Plurality won't reject invalid answers and will only print one winner

Tags: c, cs50

The majority of this code comes pre-written for the class, I only wrote the functions on the bottom but for some reason it won't reject an answer if it doesn't match one of the command line arguments.

The program is supposed to count the number of votes for each candidate and print the winner(s)(in the case of a tie)of an election.
You put the candidates in the command line arguments and the program prompts you for how many people are voting and for the votes.
It won't reject if one of the cast votes doesn't match one of the command line arguments and it only prints one winner for me despite ties.
I've gone through some walk-throughs and my code looks practically the same as others who's programs run correctly. I'm sure I'm missing something but I can't find it.

```c
    #include <cs50.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    
    // Max number of candidates
    #define MAX 9
    
    // Candidates have name and vote count
    typedef struct
    {
        string name;
        int votes;
    }
    candidate;
    
    // Array of candidates
    candidate candidates[MAX];
    
    // Number of candidates
    int candidate_count;
    // Function prototypes
    bool vote(string name);
    void print_winner(void);
    
    int main(int argc, string argv[])
    {
        // Check for invalid usage
        if (argc < 2)
        {
            printf("Usage: plurality [candidate ...]\n");
            return 1;
        }
    
        // Populate array of candidates
        candidate_count = argc - 1;
        if (candidate_count > MAX)
        {
            printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
            return 2;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
        {
            candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
            candidates[i].votes = 0;
        }
    
        int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");
    
        // Loop over all voters
        for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
        {
            string name = get_string("Vote: ");
    
            // Check for invalid vote
            if (!vote(name))
            {
                printf("Invalid vote.\n");
            }
        }
    
        // Display winner of election
        print_winner();
    }
    
    // Update vote totals given a new vote
    bool vote(string name)
    {
        // TODO
        for(int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
        {
            if(strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0)
            candidates[i].votes++;
            return true;
        }
    
        return false;
    }
    
    // Print the winner (or winners) of the election
    void print_winner(void)
    {
        //TODO
        int highestVote = -1;
        for(int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
        {
            if(candidates[i].votes > highestVote)
            {
                highestVote = candidates[i].votes;
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
        {
            if(candidates[i].votes == highestVote)
            {
                printf("%s\n" , candidates[i].name);
            }
        }
    
    }
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You don't say what this program is supposed to do. Add sample input, expected & wrong output.

Comment: My apologies. fixing that now.

Comment: `            if(strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0) {
            candidates[i].votes++;
            return true;  }` Missing block `{}` scope. Without it, you're doing only one comparison & returning from `vote()`

Comment: I really appreciate your help brother, I'm (obviously) new here and still learning. My apologies for my formatting and stupid errors. Thank you again!